# K-Means Clustering of time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, clustering, k-means

I want to create a cluster of K-Means of time series with R but I don't know where to start.

Could you recommend some articles or tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read this article https://wiki.smu.edu.sg/18191isss608g1/img_auth.php/f/fd/Time_Series_Clustering_A_Decade_Review.pdf

Also take a look at TSclust package in R https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v062i01/v62i01.pdf

You could also consider hierarchical clustering approach instead of centroid-based.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Could you recommend something about K-means clustering of times series using R ??

Comment: Just use kmeans function on your data.

Comment: But I don't need to specify that it is a time series?

Comment: You need to provide a matrix with each row for each time series values.

Comment: Perfect, but if the data is date with day, month and year I also have to transpose it?? Thanks